# Serializing a list of objects

Tags: java, serialization

I am confused on how to serialize and deserialize a list of question objects.

I have a **Survey** class that has an attribute called Questions, which is a list of **Question** objects.

I want to be able to serialize the Survey properties, along with all the properties of each question.

Unfortunately I have had no luck so far, here is what I have. Thanks for the help!

```
public void loadData(Boolean isSurvey) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Select a file: ");
    FileInputStream fileIn;

    if (isSurvey) {
        String fileName = listFiles("surveys").get(input.getIntInput(fileCount - 1));
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("surveys/" + fileName);
    } else {
        String fileName = listFiles("tests").get(input.getIntInput(fileCount - 1));
        fileIn = new FileInputStream("tests/" + fileName);
    }

    Question q = null;
    try
    {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        q = (Question) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
    }catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
        System.out.println("Not found");
        c.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Deserialized Question...");
    System.out.println("prompt: " + q.prompt);
}

public void saveData(Survey survey, Test test, Boolean isSurvey, String fileName) {
    try {
        File surveyDir = new File("surveys");
        File testDir = new File("tests");

        if ((!(surveyDir.exists()) && isSurvey)) {
            System.out.println("Creating Survey directory. . .");
            surveyDir.mkdir();
        }
        if ((!(testDir.exists())) && !(isSurvey)) {
            System.out.println("Creating Test directory. . .");
            testDir.mkdir();
        }

        if (isSurvey) {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("surveys/" + fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            for (Question question : survey.questions) {
                out.writeObject(survey.questions);
            }
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } else {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("tests/" + fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            for (Question question : test.questions) {
                out.writeObject(question);
            }
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        }


    } catch(IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'No luck' is not a problem description. Try again.

Comment: Incomplete duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598397/notserializableexception-even-after-implementing-serializable.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already implemented your object to write with the **java.io.Serializable**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Question implements Serializable {

    //Other codes here

}
```

Another thing I noticed is that you have written a collection object.

```
for (Question question : survey.questions) {
    out.writeObject(survey.questions);
}
```

But you are reading it as **Question** object.

```
q = (Question) in.readObject();
```

If the object you wrote is a Collection.  Here is an example if it is **List** collection

```
q = (List<Question>) in.readObject();
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had implemented it at the time I posted. Thanks though :(

Comment: What type of collection is **survey.questions**. You can cast that one directly since the **Collection** class already implemented **Serializable**.

Comment: survey.questions is an `ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>`