# NotSerializableException even after implementing Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, serializable

Recieving the error:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException
```

even after implementing Serializable.

I'm simply trying to serialize a **Survey** object. Here is my code, does anyone have an idea why I am receiving this error?

```
public void loadData(Survey survey, Test test, Boolean isSurvey) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ...

    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        Survey s = (Survey) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
        System.out.println("list size = " + s.questions);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void saveData(Survey survey, Test test, Boolean isSurvey, String fileName) {

    ...

    if (isSurvey) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("surveys/" + fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(survey);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    } else {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("tests/" + fileName);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(test);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Added survey class. My Question class, Main class, and Input class both implement Serializable

```
package Survey;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import IO.Input;
import Question.Question;

public class Survey implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected Main main = new Main();
protected Input input = new Input();

protected String name;
public ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();

public void setName() {
...
}

public void displayName() {
...
}

public void displayQuestions() {
...
}

public void mainMenu() {
...
}

public void addQuestionMenu() {
...
}
```

}

Comment: does the `Survey` class `implements Serializable`?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks for the response.

Comment: Keep in mind that every type of the class fields also need to be `serializable`. So, if `Survey` stores a field of type `MyType`, which does not implement `Serializable`, when you'll the mentioned exception.

Comment: @Brejuro have you made sure that the `Test` class also is serializable also that you dont have any object in the `Survey` or `Test` class that arent serializable? If so you need to either make them serializable or `transient`. If you are still having trouble I would recommend posting your `Survey` class

Comment: So, your `Survey` class stores instances of `Main` and `Input`. In order to serialize a `Survey` instance it is necessary that both classes are serializable too. Is that the case? If not, then you know what you've to do.